# Why is use of [] in variables create error 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")         
#print(type(two_digit_number))       
new_two_digit_number = int(two_digit_number)       
#print(type(new_two_digit_number))      
first_digit = new_two_digit_number[0]        
second_digit = new_two_digit_number[1]             
print(first_digit + second_digit)
```

I am getting an error regarding the use of [] but why is this stopping it from running correctly?

Comment: [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns string *([`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str))* which is sequence type. You can access chars of string using indexes like `two_digit_number[0]`. Calling `int(two_digit_number)` you convert string into integer *([`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int))* which is numeric type. You can't work with `int` using indexes. In your code you need to convert char at index `0` and char at index `1` separately, so you can sum them: `int(two_digit_number[0]) + int(two_digit_number[1])`.

Comment: you can't get individual digits from an integer like this, only from strings

Comment: The square brackets `[]` are a convenience method used to get an item in a collection. A string is just a container for characters, which is why it can be used if you don't turn it into an `int` first. An `int` object is not a collection and does not support the square brackets `[]` method.

Answer (score 2):

[`x[y]` is the syntax to access item `y` of collection `x`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) (or *to subscript* or *to index into*, for alternative terms).

On the second (non-comment) line, you convert the string returned by `input()` into an integer using `int()`, and integers aren't collections you could index; hence trying to index into the integer raises an error. On the other hand, strings (such as returned by `input()`, i.e. `two_digit_number` in your case) are [immutable sequences and as such indexable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-18); your program would work as

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")         
first_digit = two_digit_number[0]        
second_digit = two_digit_number[1]             
print(first_digit + second_digit)
```

assuming the string `two_digit_number` is indeed at least two characters long.

(If your goal is to add up the digits as if they were numbers, you could do

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")         
print(int(two_digit_number[0]) + int(two_digit_number[1]))
```

, i.e. cast both digits into integers, then sum them.)

If you do want to work with integers only, you can use `divmod(x, 10)` to get the lowest digit and the rest:

```
>>> divmod(13, 10)
(1, 3)
>>> divmod(135, 10)
(13, 5)
```

Comment: This could be a comment

Comment: @Eilonlif No, it answers the question with code examples one can't put in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, it was before the edit, you are correct.

Comment: The op appears to be expecting to add the two digits together (13 = 1 + 3) so your output would differ

Comment: @Sayse Heh, good catch. Added that example too.